# Get next table cell text for confirmation box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to get the next table cell text to use in a confirmation dialog window when deleting users.

i.e. 'Are you sure you want to delete username?'

So far I have this (simplified for the example):

html

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a class="deleteUser" href="#">Delete</a></td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Name1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a class="deleteUser" href="#">Delete</a></td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Name2</td>
    </tr>    
</table>
```

Javascript

```
$(function() {
    $(".deleteUser").click(function() {
                            confirm("Are you sure you want to delete ?")
     });
});
```

jsFiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/EARRt/

Comment: Here you go.. http://jsfiddle.net/uvFMw/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 var username = $(this).parent().parent().find('.names').text();
 confirm("Are you sure you want to delete " + username + "?")
```

here is a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/semir/gg6Nx/)

Comment: that works :) I can't upvote but I will do when i can. Thanks Mike.

Comment: @MikeW Semir's method is more portable (in case you add or reorder the table's columns), but you can also do things like `$(this).parent().siblings(":last")`. Food for thought.

Answer (score 1):

Check this link mike

[Click here](http://jsbin.com/AXOzAYe/1/)

Here is your html

```
<tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a class="deleteUser" href="#">Delete</a></td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Name1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a class="deleteUser" href="#">Delete</a></td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Name2</td>
    </tr>
```

This is the jquery should looks like

```
$(function() {
    $(".deleteUser").click(function() {
                            confirm("Are you sure you want to delete "+$(this).parent().next().next()[0].innerText+"?")
     });
});
```

Comment: thank you i will upvote when i get 15 rep. Not sure how to do that yet as i have just joined

Comment: Ok if you get solution then you can accept right button at left of my answer